# Three monitors connected to a PC and also to a laptop, so I can switch between them

Tags: hdmi, kvm

Is there a device that would allow me to connect monitors to two monitors/HDMI, which will allow me to switch between the source?

Similar to this UGREEN USB Switch Selector ([https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Selector-Computers-Peripheral-Switcher/dp/B01N6GD9JO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N6GD9JO)) I bought so that I can easily switch to a source for my keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats possible with hdmi, although i have not tried it: [https://www.amazon.com/NEWCARE-Switcher-Supports-HDCP2-2-Consoles/dp/B07RY7Y9PR/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RY7Y9PR)